# Isolate jQuery's (.off) to one specific element on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I've been working with this scrolling count-up script that animated some numbers when you scroll down to a specific spot on the page. So far, everything is working as expected, but I've noticed that within the script that kills any other jQuery scroll events for everything else on the page. Here's what I have:

```
//count up script
  $(function () {
    var fx = function fx() {
      $(".stat-number").each(function (i, el) {
        var data = parseInt(this.dataset.n, 10);
        var props = {
          "from": {
            "count": 0
          },
          "to": {
            "count": data
          }
        };
        $(props.from).animate(props.to, {
          duration: 500 * 1,
          step: function (now, fx) {
            $(el).text(Math.ceil(now));
          },
          complete:function() {
            if (el.dataset.sym !== undefined) {
              el.textContent = el.textContent.concat(el.dataset.sym)
            }
          }
        });
      });
    };

    var reset = function reset() {
      console.log($(this).scrollTop())
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1300) {
        fx()
        $(this).off("scroll");
      }
    };

    $(window).on("scroll", reset);
  });

//Other scroll script
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var sT = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (sT > 40) {
      $('.header').addClass('nav-bg');
    } else {
      $('.header').removeClass('nav-bg');
    }
  });
```

So the tricky part that I'm not sure about is how to get the two scripts to act separately from each other. If I modify the `$(this).off("scroll");` in the count up script then the animation keeps triggering every time you scroll. If I leave in `$(this).off("scroll");` it nukes all the scroll events on the page. Overall, I know *why* it's doing what it's doing. I'm just not sure how to get it so that it separates between the two events so I can get the scrolling number animation to trigger and stop and not interfere with the other scrolling header script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can namespace events which allows you to remove that namespace only using `off()` and leave other event listeners of same type active

try something like:

```
var reset = function reset() {
  console.log($(this).scrollTop())
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1300) {
    fx()
    $(this).off("scroll.myScrollName");
  }
};

$(window).on("scroll.myScrollName", reset);
```

Comment: Welllllll, shiiiiiiii....
Yeah, totally forgot about namespacing events. Ugh...Mondays.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `off` method accepts a function already attached with `on` so you can "off" only that callback and not all.

http://api.jquery.com/off/

I'm not sure how can you reference the function inside itself, as a workaround I would do something like...

```
var reset = function() {
  //your_code...
  offReset(this);
}

var offReset = function(element) {
  $(element).off(reset)
}
```